# Oracle - using nested table column in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a staging table (table_B) with columns using nested table data types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE nested_column_type AS OBJECT
          (
            abc_1            VARCHAR2(100),
            abc_2            VARCHAR2(100),
            col_id           VARCHAR2(100),
            tbl_id           NUMBER
          );

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE nested_column_tab AS TABLE OF nested_column_type;

CREATE TABLE table_B
(col_id NUMBER,
 nested_column NESTED_COLUMN_TAB)
NESTED TABLE nested_column STORE AS column_nested);
```

I want to use nested_column in the where clause of a delete statement like this:

```
DELETE FROM table_A a
WHERE tbl_id = v_tbl_id
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT col_id 
                  FROM TABLE(SELECT b.nested_column 
                               FROM table_B b 
                              WHERE tbl_id = v_tbl_id) 
                 WHERE col_id = a.col_id);
```

Table_A is my target table. My goal is to delete records from table_A where table_A.col_id NOT EXISTS in table_B.nested_column.col_id and tbl_id = v_tbl_id.

Comment: It doesn't quite answer my question. I need to delete the records in my case, and to do that I have to find all records that don't exist in the nested table column.

Comment: SO is a great site to ask questions and get answers: Just be sure to provide a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Before you ask a question consider [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Yes, I'm serious! To help us help you, generate sample data and expected results. [ascii table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) makes the output easy to read! You could also mock up data and the SQL tried using http://rextester.com/ or a similar site.  Pretty much anything is possible; it's a matter of should we do it; not can we.

Comment: @xQbert More details have been added

Answer (score 2):

Adding more on what @Ted mentioned,
you need to understand  [object name resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements009.htm#SQLRF51132) steps and must use a table alias. This is mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#ADOBJ7080).

> To avoid inner capture and similar problems resolving references,
>   Oracle Database requires you to use a table alias to qualify any
>   dot-notational reference to subprograms or attributes of objects.

In your case the query becomes:

```
DELETE FROM table_A a
      WHERE     tbl_id = v_tbl_id
            AND a.col_id NOT IN (SELECT b.col_id
                                   FROM table_B b
                                  WHERE (SELECT tb.tbl_id
                                           FROM TABLE (b.nested_column) tb) =a.tbl_id);
```

Comment: would NOT EXISTS work and be more efficient? My research suggests it would be better performance. Here's what my statement would look like with NOT EXISTS:  ...`AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT col_id FROM TABLE(SELECT b.nested_column FROM table_B b WHERE tbl_id = v_tbl_id) WHERE col_id = a.col_id)`

Comment: Well not sure as am not sure how much data you have in your table. Also in the above example i just showed how to use nested table in where clause. If you find with your research that not exist is performant, then go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the below will put you in the right path:

```
select t.primary_id, nt.*
from table_b t, table (t.nested_column) nt
```

For any further clarifications please don't hesitate to contact me again here.

Ted